# Silverlight 4.0 DataGrid Issue

Tags: datagrid, silverlight-4.0, grouping

I have changed DataGrid's DataGridRowGroupHeader's controltemplated and have placed 1 checkbox and 1 textblock instead of content presenter.
now when i do grouping... in some cases if i click on checkbox of one group... it automatically selects another group also.
can anybody please give some advice for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had ScrollbarVisibility= true for Datagrid... and when i was scrolling the grid... checkbox selection was changing... i made scrollbarvisibility to false for datagrid and placed the datagrid in one scrollviewer and it worked fine...
i am surprised from this behaviour of datagrid's scrollbars.